# Type 'WaveSurfer' is not assignable to type 'null' - typescript error when using useRef

Tags: typescript, next.js, module, wavesurfer.js

i'm working on a **music player project** and i need to use **WaveSurfer** module to create song waves and controllers, i'm working with **Next.js and typescript**, i installed and imported the module,

but when i try to use useRef on it typeScript shows this error : **Type 'WaveSurfer' is not assignable to type 'null'**

i checked out the documentation but didn't find anything useful for next.js, saw a tutorial on youtube i leave the link for you might be helpful: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NH1II2tzGv8]
here is my code :

```
import WaveSurfer from "wavesurfer.js";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function Controlbar() {
  const waveFormRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    waveFormRef.current = WaveSurfer.create({
      container: "#waveform", //waveform is the id of a div tag
      waveColor: "#4F4A85",
      progressColor: "#383351",
      url: "assets/music.mp3",
    });
  });

return (
<div id="waveform"></div>
);
};

export default Controlbar;
```

i was expecting to see song waves without any error in div tag with Id **waveform**

Answer (score 0):

When initializing the ref:

```
const waveFormRef = useRef(null);
```

You are implicitly setting the type of `waveFormRef.current` to `null` (try hovering over `waveFormRef.current` to see the type).

When trying to assign a value to it, you get the error that you can not assign another type to type 'null'.

```
waveFormRef.current = WaveSurfer.create() // won't work because other type than null
```

What you can do is type the ref explicitly as `null | WaveSurfer` (or any type you need).

```
const waveFormRef = useRef<null | WaveSurfer>(null);
```

This way, you can initialize it as `null` and later set the value to another value of type `WaveSurfer`.

---

An example for clarification (with a different type):

```
const waveFormRef = useRef<null | { name: string }>(null);
waveFormRef.current = { name: 'Tester' };
```

Comment: i tried it, now the useEffect returns this error : Argument of type '() => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.
  Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'void | Destructor'.ts(2345)

Comment: You have to type it as the type of `WaveSurfer.create()`, you can hover over create to see what type it returns. For now (if it is hard to figure out the type) you can also type as `any` (`useRef<any>`) but you should be able to figure out the type.